# split a list using linq

Tags: c#

I've the following code:

```
  var e = someList.GetEnumerator();
  var a = new List<Foo>();
  var b = new List<Foo>();
  while(e.MoveNext())  {
     if(CheckCondition(e.Current)) {
         b.Add(e.Current);
         break;
     }
     a.Add(e.Current);
 }

while(e.MoveNext())
  b.Add(e.Current)
```

This looks ugly.  Basically, iterate through a list and add elements to one list until some condition kicks in, and add the rest to another list.

Is there a better way e.g. using linq ? CheckCondition() is expensive, and the lists can be huge so I'd prefer to not do anything that iterates the lists twice.

Comment: I understand your code, but `if (e.Current)` doesn't make sense. I think you're looking to store the value of the last `MoveNext` call (from the first loop) and check to see if it was successful.

Comment: Updated to make more sense (i.e. add e.Current to `b` once CheckCondition is true, instead of handling that item outside the loop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a solution that's going to enumerate the list twice, but it won't check the condition the second time, so it should be faster:

```
var a = someList.TakeWhile(x => !CheckCondition(x)).ToList();
var b = someList.Skip(a.Count).ToList();
```

<strike>If `someList` implements `IList<T>`, each item will actually be enumerated only once, so there won't be any penalty.</strike>
*I thought `Skip` was optimized for the case of `IList<T>`, but apparently it's not... However you could easily implement your own `Skip` method that uses this optimization (see [Jon Skeet's article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/02/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-23-take-skip-takewhile-skipwhile.aspx) about this)*

It would actually be more elegant if there was a `TakeUntil` method... we can easily create it:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeUntil<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
            break;
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

With this method, the code becomes:

```
var a = someList.TakeUntil(CheckCondition).ToList();
var b = someList.Skip(a.Count).ToList();
```

Comment: +1: Nice, but I *think* `Skip` doesn't have the optimization you speak of for `IList<T>` as of .NET 4. Not sure though.

Comment: Ani is right. `Skip` has no specific optimisations for `IList<T>` so the first portion of the list will always be traversed twice.

Comment: @Ani, I just checked, it doesn't seem to be optimized for IList... I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't want to change [Ani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610856/split-a-list-using-linq/4610894#4610894), but here's a slight simplification.

```
var listToBeAdded = a;
foreach (var item in someList)
{
    if (listToBeAdded == a && CheckCondition(item))
        listToBeAdded = b;

    listToBeAdded.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I don't think there's any need for LINQ here.

I would do something like:

```
bool conditionHit = false;

foreach (var item in someList)
{
    if (!conditionHit)
        conditionHit = CheckCondition(item);

    var listToBeAdded = conditionHit ? b : a;
    listToBeAdded.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: I like this better than the OP's code because it doesn't have that questionable `if (e.Current)` in it. Ideally you would set `listTobeAdded` twice (once for each list) instead of computing it each iteration.

Comment: @Gabe: Thanks. What I really wanted to avoid was iterating the source twice and redundant computations of `CheckCondition`; both these requirements are stated in the problem.  Didn't think the OP had any issues with redundant branching based on a flag. :)

Answer (score 2):

If `someList` is a concrete [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) then this will only need a single pass through each element:

```
var a = someList.TakeWhile(x => !CheckCondition(x)).ToList();
var b = someList.GetRange(a.Count, someList.Count - a.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will end up going over the items in the first list more than once, but only calls through `CheckCondition` the first time:

```
var a = someList.TakeWhile(e => !CheckCondition(e));
var b = someList.Skip(a.Count());
```

Comment: a.Count() is going to enumerate the first query, which will need to be enumerated *again* to get the results... You need to call ToList at the end (and you'll end up with exactly my solution)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not re-using Linq's built-in methods(known for rewinding the iterators)), just reusing the OP's logic (which I believe is performant, it doesn't re-evaluate condition on next half of list) and packing it in a neat extension method and Tuple:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;



namespace Craft
{
    class Act
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var a = new List<string>
                { "I", "Love", "You", "More", "Today", "Than", "Yesterday" };

            var tx = a.SplitByCondition(s => s == "More");

            foreach (var s in tx.Item1)
                Console.WriteLine("First Half : {0}", s);

            foreach (var s in tx.Item2)
                Console.WriteLine("Second Half : {0}", s);

            Console.ReadLine();                    
        }

    }//Act

    public static class Helper
    {

        public static Tuple<List<T>, List<T>> SplitByCondition<T>
            (this IEnumerable<T> t, Func<T, bool> terminator)
        {


            var tx = new Tuple<List<T>, List<T>>
                          (new List<T>(), new List<T>()); 

            var iter = t.GetEnumerator();

            while (iter.MoveNext())
            {
                if (terminator(iter.Current))
                {
                    tx.Item2.Add(iter.Current);
                    break;
                }

                tx.Item1.Add(iter.Current);
            }

            while (iter.MoveNext())
                tx.Item2.Add(iter.Current);

            return tx;
        }      

    }//Helper

}//Craft
```

Output:

```
First Half : I
First Half : Love
First Half : You
Second Half : More
Second Half : Today
Second Half : Than
Second Half : Yesterday
```